# WCF PollingDuplexHttpBinding in non-Silverlight .NET app?

Tags: .net, wcf, binding, clickonce, wcf-binding

I am trying to implement a .NET client-application which is connecting to a web service.
The clients may sit behind firewalls or have no public IP addresses from the service perspective.

The service needs to use callbacks, however the WSDualHttpBinding which supports them cannot be
used because: "This binding requires that the client has a public URI that provides a callback endpoint for the service" (from MSDN WSDualHttpBinding remarks), which is not the case.

Similar scenario can be easily handled in Silverlight app, where PollingDuplexHttpBinding connection can be
leveraged. PollingDuplexHttpBinding seems not be available in .NET 4.0 and previous.

Is there any solution for .NET app (not-SL) to do something similar to PollingDuplexHttpBinding binding ?

Thanks

zuraff